# How to get screenshot from chrome dev tools performance frame

Tags: performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Using Chrome dev tools, how to get exact screenshot at exact time to share

[image: check Chrome devtools Performance frame, gif animation]

Answer (score 40):

**Open devtools-on-devtools:**

1. switch devtools docking mode to a separate window in the devtools settings three-dot icon.
   (when this option is activated you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to toggle docked/undocked state)
2. invoke devtools-for-devtools by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> in windows or <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> in mac when devtools window is focused

**Now, in this new devtools-for-devtools window:**

1. open `Application` tab
2. expand/open Frames - top - Images
3. click any image URL on the left to view it
4. right-click the image itself and choose `Save`
5. repeat 3-4

[image]

**To find the URL of currently shown screenshot:**

1. click the corresponding green bar in `Frames` strip under screenshot thumbnail strip
2. use element selector <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> in devtools-for-devtools and click the mini-screenshot at the bottom of the main devtools window
3. now devtools-for-devtools will show `<img>` element in the Elements tree, rightclick its `data:image/png` and `Open in Application panel`, then save it.

**Notes:**

- The images are 256 kilopixel i.e. approximately 500x500 px. This is hard-coded in devtools.
- To increase the scale of the content in the output image, resize the window before recording, so that the aspect ratio of the window matches to aspect ratio of the output image (1:1 in this case), suggested by JBress in the comments.

Comment: Thanks, so  I don't need to go devtools-for-devtools, I can just use `Frame` section

Comment: LOL great hack, bravo

Comment: This seems to work well, but the images are very low resolution. Any way to get a full resolution version with the Performance screenshots?

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm! Great solution!

Comment: Wow, I thought this was nonsense. Turns out it actually works. Great hack

Comment: I'm stuck at the step "Frames -  top - Images", what is "top"?

Comment: regarding the limited resolution: to increase the scale of the content in the output image, resize the window before recording, so that the aspect ratio of the window matches to aspect ratio of the output image (1:1 in this case)