# How to access images from chrome devtools performance recording

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

When you open chrome devtools, select the performance tab, and hit refresh with screenshots checked, you will have a recording that seems to include screenshots of the page load timeline.
I see that it is possible to save the whole analysis as a json file, and I have done that.
What I don't understand is how to access just the screenshots themselves. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Great question. This appears to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44182882/how-to-get-screenshot-from-chrome-dev-tools-performance-frame/44183341, though. I also found that the snapshot is encoded in base64 in the saved performance profile. Search for the string `"name":"Screenshot"` to find it. This base64 representation can be rendered through a browser as a (less convenient) alternative to the answer of the previously linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html

Comment: That's a very helpful comment. I had a quick browse through the json and was expecting something like jpg or png to jump out at me. No such luck. Base64 encoding was not what I expected.